# Json convert array string to object is null

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble converting my `JSON` result. I am getting a http response and I am unable to convert it to an object. I have tried changing the `Token` class into arrays and list types, but no luck. I am using .NET 6.0 Web Api.
Thanks in advance!

```
public class Tokens
{
  public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

```
var x = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// value of x is "{\"tokens\":[\"6856\",\"d70f1\",\"c66b\",\"45b\",\"3090\",\"8ac68\",\"fsf28\"]}"

var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tokens>(x);
// token is null
```

I have also tried:

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tokens>>(x);
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...Tokens]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'tokens', line 1, position 10.

Comment: Looking at the ```JSON``` it seems that your `public string Token { get; set; }` should be `public List<string> Token { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need any custom class, just parse your response

```
string x = "{\"tokens\":[\"6856\",\"d70f1\",\"c66b\",\"45b\",\"3090\",\"8ac68\",\"fsf28\"]}";
    
List<string> tokens = JObject.Parse(x)["tokens"].ToObject<List<string>>();
```

in this case you can acces to each of string separately

```
var x = tokens[0];
var y = tokens[1];
// etc
```

or if you need all of them in one string, according to your class

```
string token = string.Join(",", JObject.Parse(x)["tokens"].ToObject<string[]>());

//result "6856,d70f1,c66b,45b,3090,8ac68,fsf28";

//or more probably
string token = string.Join("", JObject.Parse(x)["tokens"].ToObject<string[]>());

//result "6856d70f1c66b45b30908ac68fsf28";
```

Comment: I dont need to parse them together. I need to add them to an array. For example, var x = token[0], var y = token[1], etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your Json string has an array of string, your model only has a string. This is why the deserialisation failing.

Change

```
public class Tokens
{
  public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

To

```
public class Tokens
{
  public IEnumerable<string> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can deserialise using the following statement

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Tokens>>(x);
```

Comment: I am still getting null for token. Could it be the way the response is formatted?

Comment: If your response is only getting a single "tokens" with a list of strings then changing `var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Tokens>>(x);` to `var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tokens>(x);` should do the trick.